# Duplicate entries in /review/low-quality-posts

Tags: support, review

This is something that I noticed in the [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com) site, but, since this is something related to the StackExchange software, I decided to post here.

There were two entries for the same question in /review/low-quality-posts.

I have attached a screenshot for a better picture.

[image: Duplicate Entries]

Is there any specific reason for this or is this a bug that needs to be fixed?

Answer (score 6):

You're not reviewing the *question*, you're reviewing the *answers* and they are different.

Comment: Thanks. Now it makes sense.

Comment: @Karthik: You couldn't figure that out by seeing the text on each one was different?